# C++ access my vector in another headerfile and cpp

Tags: c++, class, vector, header

How would I access my vector declared in aDie.h from aHisto.h, preferably not as a function? Once my vector is in my Histo.h I want to be able to modify it, change size, and just manipulate it however I choose. I am just having troubles with error messages in VS.

aDie.h

```
    #define aDie_H   
    #pragma once
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    class aDie {
    public: 
        aDie();
        void numRolls();
        void getSeed();
        void roll(); 
        void myVector(); //just gives my vector values
        void Print(); 
        std::vector<int> myV; //declare my vector, it has values stored from void myVector();

    private: 
        int i = 0;
        int Rolls;
        int dSeed;
        int die1;  
        int die2;
        int sum; 

    };
```

aHisto.h

```
#define aHistogram_H 
#include "aDie.h" 

class aHistogram : public aDie{
public: 
//adds a pointer to my vector so I can access and modify it anywhere on this header
    aHistogram();   //default const
    void getVector(); //does stuff with vector

private: 
    int i = 0;
    int min;
    int max; 
};
```

aHisto.cpp

```
#include "aHistogram.h"  
#include "aDie.h"
#include <iostream>   
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

aHistogram::aHistogram() { //default constructor 
    min = 0;
    max = 0; 

}   
void aHistogram::getVector() {

//does stuff with vector here

    }
```

Comment: You can access it using `aDie::myV`, what's the problem actually? What did you try? Why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Each inheriting class gets its own copy of the parent class' variables, so you should be able to access it with `this->myV` or even just `myV`.

Comment: @callyalater this works and actually lets me debug but if I `cout << myV.at(3);` I get a zero although that number is not zero

Comment: How are you calling `myVector()` and all that? What do your `main` and other related methods look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use the scope resolution operator because `aHistogram` inherits from `aDie`.

or you could use `this` because of the inheritance access level.

```
void aHistogram::getVector() {
      aDie::myV->something();
      //Or use this pointer
      this->myV->something();
}
```